# gtk_init fails when invoked from a process that was started from rc.local

Tags: gtk, x11

I have a script invoked from rc.local which start up a java process. When all X related things have finished, this java process starts a C++ process which call gtk_init. this call gives following error:

```
(gstinterface:2828): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

If I run first script manually from a terminal, all works fine. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you the reason: it cannot open a display connection.

Usually that happens because there is no `DISPLAY` variable exposed in the environment; you will have to export that.

Be warned that using rc.local to launch a GUI application is a very bad idea. If you need to launch the application alongside X11 you should use the X11 session scripts, or modify the script you use to launch X11.

Comment: Thanks. I've already exported DISPLAY=:0 without any success.

Comment: Then it likely means that the user that spawns the rc-local does not have access to the X file description, or that it's not available when the script is invoked. You can play with xhost and timeouts, but I should stress that you should not be using rc-local to launch X applications.